# how to add not null constraint for a column after dropping it if the table contains data

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have dropped the not null constraint for a column in postgresql. Now i need to add the not null constraint back to the column. My table has data in it already . How can i do it?

This column was created: columnname TEXT NOT NULL

Comment: Instead of `drop no null` you use `set not null` in an ALTER TABLE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in Pg [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-alter.html) you can do something like this

```
update table_name set columnname='fill null data' where columnname is null;
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN columnname SET NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN columnname SET default ' ';
```

Comment: If your table column doesn’t contain any null data query will work

Comment: Thanks @arutar!!But will the command work if i add only null values in my column ??

Comment: The particular column in my table contains only null values after giving the update statement..So what is the way to add the NOT NULL constraint back to the column?

Comment: Add default value

Comment: I changed the example above

Comment: Thanks @arutar!!
will this command work ..?
alter table table_name alter COLUMN column_name drop null ;

Comment: After the default value added to your column_name you don’t need to drop null constraint anymore all new rows will initialised with default value